# Objective c: Bad access error when using performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, performselector

Here is the problem.

1. I have a method called -(void)searchingInBackground which is running in background (performSelectorInBackground).
2. In this method, I have couple of different threads which are running in background too (performSelectorInBackground). Like this:

   ```
   -(void)searchingInBackground
   {
     @autoreleasepool {
       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getDuplicatedPictures:) withObject:copyArray];
     }

     @autoreleasepool {
       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getLocationsOfPhotos:) withObject:copyArray];
     }
   ... (and so on)
   }
   ```
3. In each of functions in threads (ie. getDuplicatedPictures, getLocationsOfPhotos...) they will generate NSStrings at the end and I will use those strings to update my text field GUI.
4. In order to update my text field GUI. I created a function called UpdateGUI which will use to help me update all of my NSStrings. Like this,

   ```
   -(void)UpdateUI
   {
      [_NumDupPhotosLabel(label for GUI)  setStringValue: resultDupPhotos(string from thread function which is getDuplicatedPictures in this case)];
       ....(includes all of my strings from threads)
   }
   ```
5. Here is the problem, when I call this UpdateGUI using performSelectorOnMainThread in each of threads function. It will give me EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Here is what I did.
   For example:

   ```
   -(void)getDupicatedPictures
   {
        resultDupPhotos = .....;
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(UpdateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
   }
   ```
6. If I do not use performSelectorOnMainThread, just set the values directly in those functions it works fine. I just want to better organize the code.

   ```
   -(void)getDuplicatedPictures
   {
        resultDupPhotos = .....;
        [_NumDupPhotosLabel  setStringValue: resultDupPhotos]; (works good and it will set the value to the GUI label)
   }
   ```

Could you guys tell me how to fix this? Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you need to use threads or could you use queues and GCD?

Comment: Maybe is a typo here, but you are using getDupicatedPictures instead getDup(l)icatedPictures and UpdateUI instead Update(G)UI

Comment: If those spelling errors are corrected as Patricio mentioned and the error still happens, try enabling NSZombies to track it down.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Comment: BTW:  Methods shouldn't be prefixed with `get` unless they are of a very specific type, which these aren't.  Also, preoperties and ivars should be prefixed with lowercase letters.   Method names should always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks for your naming suggestions @bbum. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ARC or no?
- if you have a crash, post the backtrace
- surrounding a `performInBackground:...` call with an `@autoreleasepool` does nothing (`NSAutoreleasePool` isn't going to help, either -- you need the autorelease pool to be *in the thread of execution*)
- if a variable is involved in a crash, show the variable's declaration and initialization
- spawning a bunch of threads simultaneously to do a bunch of work is likely to be slower than doing the work sequentially.  Concurrency should always be controlled.   If you have a long running task, you *might* likely want to spin up a second thread.  Or you might want to re-order operations.  The issue, though, is that running multiple threads at once, especially if those threads are doing a lot of I/O, is just going to increase contention and may likely make things slower, often a lot slower.

More likely than not, one of the objects calculated on a background thread is being released before the main thread tries to use it.   How do you ensure that `resultDupPhotos` is valid between threads?

Comment: Thanks. I keep only one performInBackground thread and get rid of others. But I heard if one function runs like more than 5 second or so, we suppose to open a new thread, don't we? Also if the @autoreleasepool does nothing. What should I do? Should I create NSAutoreleasePool *autoreleasepool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; in the function instead?